# Join table using column value as table name

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to join a table whereby the table name is a value in a column?

Here is a `TABLE` called `food`:

```
id  food_name    price_table       pricing_reference_id
1 | 'apple'     | 'daily_price'   | 13
2 | 'banana'    | 'monthly_price' | 13 
3 | 'hotdog'    | 'weekly_price'  | 17
4 | 'sandwich'  | 'monthly_price' | 9
```

There are three other tables (pricing tables): `daily_price`, `weekly_price`, and `monthly_price` tables.

*Side note*: Despite their names, the three pricing tables display vastly different kinds of information, which is why the three tables were not merged into one table

Each row in the `food` table can only be joined with one of the three pricing tables at most.

The following *does not work* -- it is just to illustrate what I am trying to get at:

```
SELECT *
FROM food
    LEFT JOIN food.price_table ON food.pricing_reference_id = daily_price.id
WHERE id = 1;
```

Obviously the query does not work. Is there any way that the name of the table in the `price_table` column could be used as the table name in a join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `left join`s:

```
select f.*,
       coalesce(dp.price, wp.price, mp.price) as price
from food f left join
     daily_price dp
     on f.pricing_reference_id = dp.id and
        f.pricing_table = 'daily_price' left join
     weekly_price wp
     on f.pricing_reference_id = wp.id and
        f.pricing_table = 'weekly_price' left join
     monthly_price mp
     on f.pricing_reference_id = mp.id and
        f.pricing_table = 'monthly_price' ;
```

For the columns you reference, you need to use `coalesce()` to combine the results from the three tables.  You say that the tables have different data, so you would need to list the columns separately.

The main reason I recommend this approach is performance.  I think the `left join`s should be faster than any solution that uses `union all`.

Answer (score 1):

Could you get your expected result using by a derived table with `UNION SELECT` which has a column of each table name?

```
SELECT *
FROM food
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 'daily_price' AS price_table, * FROM daily_price
        UNION ALL SELECT 'monthly_price', * FROM monthly_price
        UNION ALL SELECT 'weekly_price', * FROM weekly_price
    ) t
    ON food.price_table = t.price_table AND
       food.pricing_reference_id = t.id
ORDER BY food.id;
```

[dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hoaAqCFyJ2NtcN6RWWMeDB/0)